# Plotly: Follow-up How to create sunburst subplot using graph_objects?

Tags: python, plotly, sunburst-diagram

tried the example in an earlier question but I cannot get it to "render" properly:

```
# imports
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.express as px

# data
df = pd.DataFrame({'BA':  ['BA1', 'BA2', 'BA3', 'BA4','BA2'],
                   'RS':   [12, 13,15, 20, 18],
                   'RC':    ['medium','medium', 'high','high','high'] })

# plotly express figure
fig = px.sunburst(df, path=["BA", "RC"])

fig.show()

# plotly graph_objects figure
fig2=go.Figure(go.Sunburst(
                labels=fig['data'][0]['labels'].tolist(),
                parents=fig['data'][0]['parents'].tolist(),
                            )
                )
fig2.show()
```

results in:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mwtrv.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ISLfW.png)

What am I doing wrong? (i expected it to look like the first picture).. using conda + jupyter lab

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you take a look at `fig['data']`, you will see that there is a field called `ids` which tells Plotly how to connect the parents to the labels. You need to specify this as a parameter as well.

EDIT: if you want to display values the same way as px.sunburst, you also need to include the parameter `branchvalues='total'`

```
# plotly graph_objects figure
fig2=go.Figure(go.Sunburst(
    branchvalues='total',
    ids=fig['data'][0]['ids'].tolist(),
    labels=fig['data'][0]['labels'].tolist(),
    parents=fig['data'][0]['parents'].tolist(),
    values=fig['data'][0]['values'].tolist()
    )
)
fig2.show()
```

[image]

Comment: No problem, glad to have helped :)

Comment: Derek, when adding the values (values=sbfig['data'][0]['values'].tolist()) then the rendering "breaks" again, what am I still not getting? :)

Comment: That seems strange... I'll look into this when I have the chance!

Comment: I think as a general rule, if you are trying to recreate a plotly fig, you should always look into `fig['data']` to make sure you are including everything important. Include the parameter `branchvalues='total'` and you should get the expected sunburst chart.